# jquery icheck callback - which one was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, icheck

I'm using the [iCheck jQuery library](https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck) and can't seem to figure out a way to detect which element the event pertains to. Setting up any of the callbacks always returns every element, not just the one I clicked. I need to find which element was toggled, not all of them.

```
$("input").on('ifToggled', function(e){
  console.log(this); //returns all 3 checkboxes below
  console.log(e.currentTarget); //returns all 3 checkboxes below
  console.log(e.target); //returns all 3 checkboxes below
});

<input type="checkbox" class="icheck" name="exercise[27][save_as_default]" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="icheck" name="exercise[498][save_as_default]" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="icheck" name="exercise[240][save_as_default]" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;" value="1">
```

Comment: Maybe try ifChanged instead, the state change can be detect by jquery as well, not sure why you need to use the lib's method

Comment: The native jQuery doesn't detect it because the checkbox itself in iCheck isn't a checkbox (it's a div with a background image that looks like a checkbox). Using the library basically makes the look of the checkbox consistent across different browsers and platforms.

Comment: Right, it's probably more useful to post the generated code

Comment: Hah, this is silly, but I had to give the elements an ID. After that, it worked as expected.

Comment: Might of been in their documentation somewhere. When I scan it I did not see any mentions

Answer (score 1):

Once I gave the checkbox  elements unique ID's, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use class name instead of "input".

```
$('.icheck').on('ifToggled', function () {
      if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
          console.log($(this).val());
      }   
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without any external library

```
$(".icheck").on('change', function(){
    console.log(this.name);
});
```